# Rails 7 Unpermitted parameters:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

am gonna add the error and also my controller where i think its the source of the error
I have tried different solutions, but none of them worked, the weird thing, my code was working this morning, and this error only occurs after I added new tables to the database

this is my controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Sign up successful.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def index
  @users = User.all
end

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:full_name, :password, 
  :password_confirmation])
end
```

end

and this is the error

> Unpermitted parameters: :full_name, :password_confirmation. Context: { controller: Devise::SessionsController, action: new, request: #ActionDispatch::Request:0x00007fc5b5ca5a58, params: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"full_name"=>"shaker abu drais", "email"=>"shaker_abady@yahoo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up", "controller"=>"devise/sessions", "action"=>"create"} }

I have tried different solutions, but none of them worked, the weird thing, my code was working this morning, and this error only occurs after I added new tables to the database

Answer (score 1):

What is it that you're actually trying to acheive here? If you're trying to just add additional attributes to the user registration then this code is just completely misguided.

You can whitelist additional attributes either through your ApplicationController which is the superclass for Devise's controllers:

```ruby
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  
  private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:full_name, :password, 
    :password_confirmation])
  end
end
```

Or by creating a subclass of `Devise::RegistrationsController` and configuring the routes if you need to customize the workflow further:

```ruby
devise_for :user, controllers: { registrations: 'my_registrations' }
```

```ruby
class MyRegistrationsController < ::Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  # Don't clobber the entire `#create` method. Especially not without actually 
  # replicating its functionality
  def create 
    super do |user|
      # do something with the newly registered user
    end
  end
  
  private

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:full_name, :password, 
    :password_confirmation])
  end  
end
```

Note that I wouldn't call this controller `UsersController`. There is a reason why Devise choose the name `Registrations` - its because it differentiates between signing up and for example if users are created by an admin.